# Override django's model delete method for bulk deletion

Tags: django, model, bulk, imagefield

I'm overriding Django's model delete method in order to delete orphan files in the disk for image fields, something like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
    ...
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.img.delete()
        super(Image, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works fine when I delete single objects from the admin, but when I select multiple objects and delete them, this doesn't seem to get called. I have been googling for a while but haven't hit the right keywords to get the answer for this, nor the official documentation seems to talk about this subject.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[It does](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#delete):

> The delete() method does a bulk delete and does not call any delete() methods on your models. It does, however, emit the pre_delete and post_delete signals for all deleted objects (including cascaded deletions).

For that to work, you can override delete method on `QuerySet`, and then apply that `QuerySet` as manager:

```
class ImageQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for obj in self:
            obj.img.delete()
        super(ImageQuerySet, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)

class Image(models.Model):
    objects = ImageQuerySet.as_manager()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
    ...
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.img.delete()
        super(Image, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I think that I read that in the documentation but didn't know it applied to the admin's bulk delete. Anyway, i liked your solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: There is one caveat with this approach, now you can do: `Image.objects.delete()` and this will wipe out your table.

Answer (score 8):

Delete method of queryset works directly on the database. It does not call `Model.delete()` methods. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects):

> Keep in mind that this will, whenever possible, be executed purely in SQL, and so the delete() methods of individual object instances will not necessarily be called during the process. If you’ve provided a custom delete() method on a model class and want to ensure that it is called, you will need to “manually” delete instances of that model (e.g., by iterating over a QuerySet and calling delete() on each object individually) rather than using the bulk delete() method of a QuerySet.

If you want to override Django administration interface's default behavior, you can write a custom `delete` action:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Another method is to override `post_delete` (or `pre_delete`) signal instead of `delete` method:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_delete

> Like pre_delete, but sent at the end of a model’s delete() method **and a queryset’s delete() method**.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will give them a try but im marking GwynBleidD's answer as accepted cause i preffer his aproach (seems cleaner).

Answer (score 8):

I believe this issue is addressed in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

where it says:

> Overridden model methods are not called on bulk operations
>
> Note that the delete() method for an object is not necessarily called when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet or as a result of a cascading delete. To ensure customized delete logic gets executed, you can use pre_delete and/or post_delete signals.
>
> Unfortunately, there isn’t a workaround when creating or updating objects in bulk, since none of save(), pre_save, and post_save are called.

As suggested in the docs above, I believe a better solution is to use the `post_delete` signal, like so:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Image(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
    ...

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Image)
def delete_image_hook(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    instance.img.delete()
```

Unlike overriding the `delete` method, the `delete_image_hook` function should be called on bulk deletes and cascading deletes as well. Here is more information on using Django's Signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders

**Note on previous answers:**
Some of the earlier posts suggest overriding the `delete` method of QuerySet, which may have performance implications and other unintended behavior. Perhaps those answers were written before Django's Signals were implemented, but I think using Signals is a cleaner approach.

Comment: Signals never let me down. I always prefer this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer may not work for everyone. I couldn't get it to work on Django 3.2, but it may only be because I already had a custom manager and was not confident that I could combine my customizations to a models.Manager with customizations to a models.QuerySet.

I found that overriding [delete_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_queryset) (available in Django 2.1+) on the model's admin (as described in [this thorough and fully-illustrated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56165570/706797) from user [Kushan Gunasekera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6194097/kushan-gunasekera) to another related SO question) was quick and easy.