# How to ignore custom model manager and overrided delete method in admin?

Tags: python, django

I override `delete` method (have made object non-deleteable and set 'active' field to false) in custom `QuerySet` in custom `ModelManager`.
Is there any way to ignore custom manager in admin panel so I can actually delete objects from there?

#### edit 1

First thought: I can specify another name for custom Manager. But now it's treated as default... And how to bypass obj.delete()?

#### edit 2

Solution for first problem is to add custom manager alongside with default:

```
objects = models.Manager()
active_manager = EventManager()
```

Solution to second problem is to add param to the custom `delete` method:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    force = kwargs.pop('force', False)
    ...
```

Comment: add parameter to your custom `delete` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django admin: override delete method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196313/django-admin-override-delete-method)

Comment: @BearBrown it works! Can u create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: i added but please edit it if need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameter to your custom `delete` method. for example:

```
def delete(self, super=True):
    if super:
         return self.get_queryset().delete()
    else:
        # Your custom code here
```