# Add, Delete, Update to multiple database by subclassing django.db.models.Model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, multi-database

I want to write to add, update delete to multiple database by using [django.db.models.Model](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py)

I am able to add to multiple database by setting up [multi-db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/) in settings.py

So setting file look like

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': config['DB_NAME'],
        'USER': config['DB_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': config['DB_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': config['DB_HOST'],
        'PORT': config['DB_PORT'],
    },
    'tableau': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'tableau',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    },
}
```

Then I create subclass of `django.db.models.Model` and model in my app's `model.py`

```
from django.db.models import Model

class MultiDbModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for dbname in settings.DATABASES:
            super(MultiDbModel, self).save(using=dbname)

class People(MultiDbModel):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    country = CharField(max_length=255)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(App, self).save(args, kwargs)
```

So when I am creating new object its getting saved to both database.

```
People.objects.create(name='alok', location='India')
```

To this approach I want to add capability of `update` and `delete` query also like `create` is working properly.

What methods get called when `update` and `delete` query runs or how can I add capability of delete and update to multiple database?

Comment: `obj=People.objects.using('tableua').get(name='alok',location='india')` then `obj.name='singh'` to update `obj.save()` to save and `obj.delete()` to delete

Comment: when I will not get any solution in that case I have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would override admin methods.`save_model` caters both create and update method. add `delete_model` for [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196313/django-admin-override-delete-method) object.

Refer to:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods