# How do I make sure a model field is and incremental number for my model?

Tags: python, django

I have the following model in django:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    page_number = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

and I would like to make sure that this page number keeps being a sequence of integers without gaps, even if I delete some pages in the middle of the existing pages in the data base. For example, I have pages 1, 2 and 3, delete page 2, and ensure page 3 becomes page 2.

At the moment, I am not updating the page_number, but rather reconstructing an increasing sequence without gaps in my front end by:

- querying the pages
- sorting them according to page_number
- assigning a new `page_order` which is incremental and without gaps

But this does not seem to the be best way to go...

Comment: How are you deleting the pages?- is it through the admin pages or do you have a view?

Comment: Right now it's through the admin, I am developping a survey app. But in the future there should be custom views to manage the survey design (associated to some backend management app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you'd have to manually bump all of the pages down

When you get to custom views you'd do something like this:

```py
def deletePage(request):
    if request.method = 'POST':
        pageObj = Page.objects.filter(page_number=request.POST.get('page_number')).first()
        if pageObj:
            pageObj.delete()

            # Note: Using F() means Django doesn't need to Fetch the value from the db before subtracting
            #   - It's a blind change, it's faster though
            from django.db.models import F
            for i in Page.objects.filter(page_number__gt=request.POST.get('page_number')):
                i.page_number = F('page_number') - 1
                i.save()

        else:
            # No Page Object Found
            # Raise some error
            pass
```

The admin page is tougher tho, you'd basically do the same thing but in functions described in: [Django admin: override delete method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196313/django-admin-override-delete-method)

- **Note:** Deleting multiple would be tough, especially if you're deleting page 2 + 4 + 5. Possible, but a lot of thinking involved