# Django model.delete() method returning successful delete but not actually deleting

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.0.

I make an AJAX call to a function in Django that should allow a user to vote on a post or remove their vote from a post. When I call the `.delete()` method on a model, the model returns a result as if it was being deleted, but the record is not removed from the database. Here is the Django function:

```
if request.method != 'POST':
    raise Http404

post_id = request.POST.get('postId')
vote_type = request.POST.get('voteType')

# If vote_type isn't valid, 404
if (not any(vote_type in allowed_vote_type
        for allowed_vote_type in Vote.ALLOWED_VOTE_TYPES)
        or not 'null'):
    raise Http404

post_queryset = Post.objects.filter(pk=post_id)
post = get_object_or_404(post_queryset)

try:
    vote = Vote.objects.get(
        post=post,
        user=request.user
    )
    print('Vote object found')
    # User has already voted on this post.
    # Update user's vote.
    if vote_type == 'upvote':
        print('vote_type is upvote')
        if vote.vote_type == 'upvote':
            print('Deleting vote.')
            # User just upvoted twice. Expected behavior: Remove their vote

            ##################
            ## THIS IS MY PROBLEM
            ##################
            vote_delete_result = vote.delete()
            print(vote_delete_result)
            if vote_delete_result[0]:
                # If upvote was successfully deleted, reduce post score
                post.score -= 1
            ##################
            ## END PROBLEM
            ##################
        elif vote.vote_type == 'downvote':
            print('Changing from downvote')
            # User is changing from downvote to upvote
            vote.vote_type = vote_type
            # Add 2 to post.score
            post.score += 2
        else:
            print('Vote type was not downvote, so we did nothing.')
    elif vote_type == 'downvote':
        # Repeat all the stuff above, but for downvote...
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print('Vote object NOT found')
    # User has not yet voted on this post.
    # Create a new vote.
    vote = Vote(
        user=request.user,
        post=post,
        vote_type=vote_type,
    )

    # Update post score.
    if vote_type == 'upvote':
        post.score += 1
    elif vote_type == 'downvote':
        post.score -= 1

if vote:
    vote.save()
post.save()
data = serializers.serialize(
    'json',
    post_queryset,
    fields=('id','score')
)
return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

When calling `vote_delete_result = vote.delete()` the value of `vote_delete_result` is `(1, {'posts.Vote': 1})` as is expected [according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects).

Unlike [this question where the `model.delete()` method is not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471909/django-model-delete-not-triggered), we know the `model.delete()` method is being called since `vote_delete_result` returns a tuple that confirms it.

[One Google Group discussed the idea that `.delete()` only worked on QuerySets](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/U1NHInQBjEc) but that post was back in 2012. The Django 2.0 docs suggest that `model.delete()` should work just fine. Even so, I have tested my issue using a QuerySet instead like this (still getting the same issue):

```
vote_delete_result = Vote.objects.filter(pk=vote.id).delete()
print(vote_delete_result)
if vote_delete_result[0]:
    post.score -= 1
```

**How do I delete my Vote record from the database?**

Comment: How are you verifying that the vote is not deleted?

Comment: Through Django admin before and after the function is run.

Comment: Later on you have: `if vote: vote.save()` - that's just saving the extact model instance back again after you've deleted it, no? You're not taking into account whether you want it deleted or not...

Comment: Also - since you don't have a default `vote` - it's only set within the `try` - where it's not found, you'll get a `NameError` upon reaching the above anyway - looks like you need to do some refactoring there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm going to make a few suggestions, maybe you'll like them.

**1. Don't create a separate model to record votes**

You can create two many-to-many fields to record the upvoters and downvoters:

```
class Post:
    upvoters = ManyToManyField(User)
    downvoters = ManyToManyField(User)
```

Now, if a user upvotes a post, all you have to do is add that user to the `upvoters` field:

```
if vote_type == upvote:
    if already upvoted:
        # undo vote
        post.upvoters.remove(user)
    else:
        # add vote
        post.upvoters.add(user)
```

Same goes for downvoting.

---

**2. Move the upvote/downvote logic in your model methods**

I once created a project where most of my model related logic was in views, and I regretted it very much later. A better way to organize the code is to keep the database related logic in the models, as much as possible, and frontend/template related logic in the views.

So, to move all that upvote/downvote logic to your models, you can create special methods for that:

```
class Post:
    ...
    def vote(self, user, vote_type):
        if vote_type == upvote:
            self.upvoters.add(user)

        # and so on
```

And then, you can call `Post.vote` method to do upvote/downvote:

```
post.vote(request.user, vote_type)
```